# have to show YcbCr color space image?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, color-space

I have to show YCbCr color space using matlab. i can get the YcbCr values but i don't know how to show color space in below format, can any one help me?
[image: YCbCr color Space]

Comment: Are you just trying to make a scatter plot of all points that you have in an image. If so you can simply use [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)

Comment: no problem, next time you post a picture as well, please make sure it is a decent resolution. This is very grainy and the numbers are barely legible. I know the intent here is not to actually read the numbers, but when people see posts like this, many are almost immediately turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume for now that you want to make a 3-D scatter plot, because that is what the picture you posted looks like. This is relatively simple, and can be done as follows

```
pep_rgb = imread('peppers.png');
pep_ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(pep_rgb);
x = pep_ycbcr(:,:,1);
y = pep_ycbcr(:,:,2);
z = pep_ycbcr(:,:,3);
scatter3(x,y,z);
```

If you already have the image in YCbCr then you do not have to do the conversion from RGB, this was done in my example to make the default peppers image in matlab is converted to that colorspace

Comment: Hi , i looked at your code and i thought its correct but when i used it for my image it gives an error Error using scatter3 (line 61)
X, Y and Z must be vectors of the same length.

Error in Untitled2 (line 7)
scatter3(x,y,z);

Comment: then there is something wrong with the dimensionality of your image. maybe you are not separating the Y, Cb, and Cr, dimensions properly. Each dimension should be the same size.